# my bundle doesn't update, always shows old version of site

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Webpack doesn't update my bundle and I always get same old version of my website when use `npm run build`.

My directory:

----MyProject
--------------src
------------------index.js
------------------index.html
--------webpack.config.js
--------package.json

I tried reinstalling webpack, it helped once, but after does not update again no matter how many times I reinstall it.

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },


  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback:true
    },


  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[path][name]-[hash:8].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-babel-react-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js --hot",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode production --hot",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-bootstrap-webpack": "^1.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-transition": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 0.2%",
    "last 15 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: When you say it won't update the bundle, do you mean your browser always shows the 'same old version' or the actual `bundle.js` _file_ isn't updated? If it's the browser, try using private mode because browsers will cache the bundle.js is not told specifically **not** to do it. See if that displays the newest version of your website

Comment: Yes it helped. I feel so stupid now :), thank you a lot!!!    I tried to clean cache in browser before, but the point is that I did it for the past 7 days only, after running in private mode it works, so I cleaned cache entirely.

Comment: So I guess turning off "cache" in browser is the solution for the future, right?

Comment: Added an answer where I attempt to describe a solution in more detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is related to the browser caching the `bundle.js` for an unspecified amount of time.

The traditional way to develop is to use a devserver and changes made should be auto-reloaded based on when content of the source files changes.

For production you'll want to add the `contenthash` to the output filename like so

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.[contenthash].js",
    publicPath: "/"
  }
```

That would result in the file being named something like `bundle.3f2b48a634975adb9b7e.js` which again will prompt the browser to reload the bundle the next time the website is loaded since the bundle filename doesn't match the cached bundle filename.

I recommend reading [the Webpack caching documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) for more details